# Push all data fields to the top of a Details band inside a report

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to push all data from different rows to the top, everything at the same level.

I have this data, each one with a diferent day name on it, and I draw them on different 'columns' in my report.

Problem is that data for the first column gets at the top of the report, and data for the second column gets below them at the 2nd column. And so forth.

I wish to have something like this:

```
MONDAY    TUESDAY    WEDNESDAY    ...
-------------------------------------
Hello     World      Here I Am
There     More Data  Sample Data
```

But I'm getting t his:

```
MONDAY    TUESDAY    WEDNESDAY    ...
-------------------------------------
Hello
There
          World
          More Data
                      Here I Am
                      Sample Data
```

I'm looking for the correct combination of options at the propoerties of each data field, but couldn't get it to work.

I also have tried getting all the data fields inside a Frame and playing around with the Fram properties too, but no success yet.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

EDIT:

right now, my data fields have a Print When Expression on each 'column', so that they draw themselves on the right column, according to the day they belong to

Answer (score 2):

Your data is displayed on different rows, because each row corresponds to a row from the result set. You can control this behaviour using a report property called `Print Order`. In your case, it is set to `Vertical`. If you change to `Horizontal`, then each column in your report will correspond to one row in your result set. 
You can find some useful tips [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530934/how-print-field-values-horizontally) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894563/displaying-custom-number-of-elements-horizontally-how-to-do).