# How to print horizontally in iReport?

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I am working on a Java Swing project that prints small cards on A4 size paper.

- Data Source is : Table Model Data Source.
- iReport version : 2.0.3

I want to print cards grid in the paper. I deleted other columns without details columns and Added field `COLUMN_1` drop it into details column.

It successfully prints my values vertically like this, It means Java Code parses all values and parameters as expected.

- AA
- BB
- CC
- DD
- EE
- FF

But I want to print it like a grid with three columns.

- AA | BB | CC
- DD | EE | FF

I think this is adjusted to be in the report. Any idea how to do this? 
any suggestions would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying custom number of elements horizontally. How to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8894563/displaying-custom-number-of-elements-horizontally-how-to-do)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching threads on jasper community I found an answer and it works for me.

I removed codes like :

`<group name="barcode">
 <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{barcode}]]></groupExpression>
 </group>`

in my `report.jrxml` 
[Here is Jasper Community Thread.](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/3672)

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Set Column Count = 3 in your jrxml template.

Comment: It's all? Any additional settings\properties?

Comment: Yes I tried, Set the column count 3 and set print order horizontal. I get three columns in iReport preview but it only prints two columns when I print. What am I missing?

Comment: Print order = Vertical